# Adding multiple values in multiple entries via jq

Tags: jq

Suppose I have some json formatted something like this (I've removed the bits I'm not interested in, I can filter those out):

```
{
  "name": "db1",
  "size": 40000,
  "items": 500,
  "mutations": 2,
  "tombstones": 4,
  "views_count": 8,
  "fts_count": 0,
  "index_count": 0,
  "analytics_count": 0
}
{
  "name": "db2",
  "size": 11,
  "items": 900,
  "mutations": 3,
  "tombstones": 0,
  "views_count": 0,
  "fts_count": 0,
  "index_count": 0,
  "analytics_count": 0
}
{
  "name": "db1",
  "size": 10,
  "items": 6,
  "mutations": 5,
  "tombstones": 0,
  "views_count": 0,
  "fts_count": 0,
  "index_count": 1,
  "analytics_count": 0
}
```

How can I get a summary of all the elements of the entry, but only for each name (here we can see db1 mentioned twice so I'd like something like this):

```
{
  "name": "db1",
  "size": 40010,
  "items": 506,
  "mutations": 8,
  "tombstones": 4,
  "views_count": 8,
  "fts_count": 0,
  "index_count": 1,
  "analytics_count": 0
}
{
  "name": "db2",
  "size": 11,
  "items": 900,
  "mutations": 3,
  "tombstones": 0,
  "views_count": 0,
  "fts_count": 0,
  "index_count": 0,
  "analytics_count": 0
}
```

This is a subset of the complete json which has around 18000 lines (but there's only 11 names).

Comment: Have you tried anything? How would you determine which one to pick, since there's multiple entries with the same name?

Comment: I've created a map and used add, but it's just got one entry with the most recent number in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--slurp` the input to get an array and then use `group_by` to make groups (arrays) according to any criteria (`.name` in your case). If you want just one for each name, take one (e.g. the `first`) of each such group. Finally, apply `[]` to disassemble the surrounding array.

```sh
jq --slurp 'group_by(.name) | map(first)[]'
```

```json
{
  "name": "db1",
  "size": 40000,
  "items": 500,
  "mutations": 2,
  "tombstones": 4,
  "views_count": 8,
  "fts_count": 0,
  "index_count": 0,
  "analytics_count": 0
}
{
  "name": "db2",
  "size": 11,
  "items": 900,
  "mutations": 3,
  "tombstones": 0,
  "views_count": 0,
  "fts_count": 0,
  "index_count": 0,
  "analytics_count": 0
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9jKvjoMaJ5)

Note: With a little bit of more effort, you could also `--stream` (and then `reduce`) the input (instead of using `--slurp`) but 18000 lines isn't that big for memories nowadays, so I thought this would be the more reasonable approach.

Comment: Thankyou, this seems to work perfectly. I wasn't that close to be honest :D Had just about figured the map and then I was looking at adding values, but coming back with all sorts of sh*t. This works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, you added the values, I didn't notice. To achieve this, replace `first` with some kind of `reduce`, e.g. to add up all values but `.name` (obviously) try `reduce .[] as $o ({name: first.name}; reduce ($o | keys[] | select(. != "name")) as $k (.; .[$k] += $o[$k]))`. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SSc2a3J7-h)